# How to capture value between two strings in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, text

i'm trying to capture a value between two strings using VB.NET

Each line from the file i'm reading in from can contain many different parameters, in any order, and I'd like to store the values of these parameters in their own variables. Two sample lines would be:

identifier="121" messagecount="112358" timestamp="11:31:41.622" column="5" row="98" colour="ORANGE" value="Hello"

or it could be:

identifier="1121" messagecount="1123488" timestamp="19:14:41.568" valid="true" state="running"

Also, this may not be the sole text in the string, there may be other values before and after (and in between) the parameters i would like to capture.

So essentially i'd need to store everything between 'identifier="' and it's closing '"' into an identifier variable, and so on... As the order of these parameters within each line can change, i can't simply stick the first value in one variable each time, I have to refer to them specifically by what their name is (identifier, messagecount) etc.

Can anyone help? Thanks. I guess it would be via a regular expression, but i'm not too hot on those. I'd prefer to have each expression for each paramater within it's own statement, rather than being all in one, thanks.

Comment: Just convert it in an array/Collection

Comment: Is this part of an XML file or are these the actual values that appear per line?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to split the data into manageable clumps, and then go through it.  Something like this to start you off.

```
Private Sub ProcessMyData(LineOfData As String)

    ' NOTE!  This assumes all your 'names' have no spaces in!
    Dim vElements = LineOfData.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    For Each vElement In vElements
        Dim vPair = vElement.Split({"="c})

        Dim vResult = vPair(1).Trim(Convert.ToChar(34))

        Select Case vPair(0).ToLower
            Case "identifier"
                MyIDVariable = CInt(vResult)

            Case "colour"
                MyColourVariable = vResult

            ' etc., etc.
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

You can define the variables you want locally in the sub [function], and then return a list/dictionary/custom class of the things you're interested in.

Comment: That works fine, but it's sticking a set of double-quotes around the extracted strings still, can you modify it to remove those?

Comment: Added.  Simply apply a .Trim to the string and specify which characters you want to trim off.
Please mark this as the answer if you're happy with it :D

Comment: Ah, that's not working, it's now including other extraneous information from the line, that I want to ignore. This is the full line: <transaction identifier="101" messagecount="107870" timestamp="14:34:21.700"><data column="9" row="30" colour="YELLOW" value=""/></transaction> it's now putting the '<transaction' as an element, along with the '><data' and the '/></transaction>' which i'd like to be ignored.

Comment: Well you neglected to mention that the data was in XML format.  In fact, your question clearly states it's in a different format.  You might want to read about how to use `XMLDocument` or similar.  Ten times easier and cleaner than breaking the string up manually.

Comment: Sorry, well it's single statements in a single line, rather than in an XML tree. I assumed it wasn't true XML. It's a series of single xml lines, all unrelated to each other, not an xml tree file. They all begin with transaciton, it's just the paramters in between that differ.

Comment: `<transaction>` has sub element `<data>`.  It is XML, just very sparse, and not necessarily up to the standards.

Comment: Sorry, yes there's data too. I know it's not up to standards but it's what I have to work with. Can XMLdocument extract each attribute from a single statement?

Comment: I understand, you've got what you've got.  To be honest, I haven't dabbled with XML much, but I'm sure a quick search for some other questions will help you understand the basics.  It's the terminology that might puzzle to start with.

Comment: Not to worry, fixed it :) If I convert each line into xml, and have XmlDocument parse through that, it works fine, thank you! :)

Comment: Thank god... I'm at home now and not really wanting to waste my evening!  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample how you can go about that. It converts one line into a dictionary.

This will capture any string consisting of `a-z`-characters (case-insensitive) as the attribute name, and then catch any character other than `"` in the value string. (If `"` can occur in the string as `""` you need to add some treatment for that.)

```
    Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
    [...]

            Dim s As String = 
               "identifier=""121"" messagecount=""112358"" " &
               "timestamp=""11:31:41.622"" column=""5"" row=""98"" " &
               "colour=""ORANGE"" value=""Hello"""
            Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

            Dim rx As New Regex("([a-z]+)=""(.*?)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

            Dim rxM As MatchCollection = rx.Matches(s)
            For Each M As Match In rxM
                d.Add(M.Groups(1).Value, M.Groups(2).Value)
            Next

            ' Dictionary is ready
            ' test output
            For Each k As String In d.Keys
                MsgBox(String.Format("{0} => {1}", k, d(k)))
            Next
```